# Securing apache server for mobile app backend

Tags: android, apache, mobile, amazon-web-services, backend

I am new to backend development and security. I have a `LAMP` stack setup on `AWS` and have a Android application with can `POST` and `GET` messages to this server. I want to now make the server more secure.

Currently I have no security in place and have no idea where to start. I tried implementing `SSL` with Apache but didn't have much luck.

Any links to tutorials or reading or any other help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to get started would be to ensure you are following the best practices for AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233
Besides those on the list, setting up your firewall rules as tightly as possible, running something like fail2ban to prevent constant login attempts, running Apache in a chroot jail, and other things like that are all good places to start. Security is a never-ending process.

Setting up SSL (TLS) for your web service is an excellent idea and will prevent anybody from snooping the data going between your app users and your service. Getting SSL up and running can be a bit daunting your first time, but I would suggest starting with the Apache documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html and talking with the representative at the company you purchased your SSL certification to explain everything they provide you. If you don't understand the basics of TLS, the Wikipedia article isn't a bad place to get a nice overview.